# How to Retrieve Encoded Data from DB in MVC Model and Decode it for display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building a Web Application using ASP.NET MVC C#.
I am encoding the data on the way in using a function:

```
public string Encode(string encodeMe)
{
    byte[] encoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodeMe);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);
}
```

This is called in  the class constructor:

```
public Booking(string name, string phone, string email, string date)
{
    Name = Encode(name);
    Phone = Encode(phone);
    Email = Encode(email);
    PreferredTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
}
```

So far so good, and the encrypted data is written to the database.

However, I want to decode that data when I read it back, using this function:

```
public static string Decode(string decodeMe)
{
    byte[] encoded = Convert.FromBase64String(decodeMe);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encoded);
}
```

I have tried adding this in the Set{} statements like this:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = Decode(value);
    }
}
```

Now what happens? The booking record is correctly encoded by the constructor in      `db.Booking.Add(booking);` , but this Set{} statement is called during the execution of `db.SaveChanges();` and unencrypted data is added to the database, but previously encrypted data is correctly decoded on retrieval for Display. Attempting to decode unencrypted data causes an exception.

Comment: Sorry but what problem are you even trying to solve by making everything longer (as in more data) and slower? Also, encoding != encrypting. This seems totally unneccesary. Any decent database can store strings as they are without Base64 encoding, and anyone with an ounce of insight can decode it if encryption *was* what you're after.

Comment: At this point I am not concerned about the methods used to encode or decode, that can be changed later. I want the data in the database to be encrypted. I just want to master the technique of encrypting it on the way in, and decrypt it on retrieval for display..

Comment: Ok, got it. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your property is unbalanced: it Decodes when set-ting, but it does not Encode anywhere.

Also note that Entity Framework **uses these properties** just as well as you do. So EF calls the getter, which gets `_name`, which was set using `_name = Decode(value);`. The result: EF never sees the encoded value, it only exists for a split second in `value`.

To guarantee that data in the properties is always encoded you should keep the encoding/decoding out of the properties, and do it yourself if you need "the real data" (e.g. when displaying).

So the property becomes just:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

or even

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In the `Booking` constructor you are already using `Encode()` before assigning to the properties.
In all other places where you need the 'actual' values you will need to use `Decode(Name)`, etc.